# floating point number imprecision while iterating

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have a function that computes a point in 3d spaced based on a value in range `[0, 1]`. *The problem I'm facing is, that a binary floating-point number cannot represent exactly 1.*

The mathematical expression that is evaluated in the function is able to compute a value for `t=1.0`, but the value will never be accepted by the function because it checks if for the range before computing.

```
curves_error curves_bezier(curves_PointList* list, curves_Point* dest, curves_float t) {
    /* ... */
    if (t < 0 || t > 1)
        return curves_invalid_args;
    /* ... */
    return curves_no_error;
}
```

How can I, with this function, compute the 3d point at `t=1.0`? I heard something about an `ELLIPSIS` some time ago that I think had to do with such an issue, but I'm not sure.

Thanks

**EDIT**: Ok, I'm sorry. I assumed a float cannot represent exactly 1, because of the issue I'm facing. The problem may be because I was doing an iteration like this:

```
for (t=0; t <= 1.0; t += 0.1) {
    curves_error error = curves_bezier(points, point, t);
    if (error != curves_no_error)
        printf("Error with t = %f.\n", t);
    else
        printf("t = %f is ok.\n", t);
}
```

Comment: Hmm can you use decimal?

Comment: `binary floating-point number cannot represent exactly 1` [are you sure](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049046048)? There are problems with 1.) fractional numbers that would have infinite fractional digits in radix of 2 2.) numbers that are too small to exactly represent 3.) numbers that are too large to represent without losing precision. But 1.0 is none of them!

Comment: "The problem I'm facing is, that a binary floating-point number cannot represent exactly 1." <- Umm, sure it can, that's one of the easiest.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it cannot represent 1, shouldn't have done this before researching. Please see my edit.

Comment: @CarlPalsson Decimal? :)

Comment: You probably heard about `EPSILON`, not `ELLEPSIS`.

Comment: Floats indeed can represent 1, but a result of computations that should equal 1 can still divert because of rounding errors

Comment: Sorry c# here... didn't notice the C tag.. :(

Comment: Also note that when we talk about floating-point we are often, but certainly not always, referring to IEEE754 floating-point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (t=0; t <= 1.0; t += 0.1) {
```

your problem is that a binary floating point number cannot exactly represent `0.1`.

The closest 32-bit single precision IEEE754 floating point number is 0.100000001490116119384765625 and the closest 64-bit double precision one 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. If the arithmetic is performed strictly at 32-bit precision, the result of adding `0.1f` ten times to 0 is

```
1.00000011920928955078125
```

If intermediate computations are performed at greater precision than `float` has, it could result in exactly `1.0` or even slightly smaller numbers.

To fix your problem, in this case you could use

```
for(k = 0; k <= 10; ++k) {
    t = k*0.1;
```

because `10 * 0.1f` is exactly `1.0`.

Another option is to use a small tolerance in your `curves_bezier` function,

```
if (t > 1 && t < 1 + epsilon) {
    t = 1;
}
```

for a suitably small epsilon, maybe `float epsilon = 1e-6;`.

Comment: The `t = k * 0.1f` thing is perfect. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Had I seen your answer, I wouldn't have put much effort into mine.

Comment: @ppeterka Computing `i / 10.0` as in your answer gives a very slightly better distribution of errors compared to `i * 0.1f` as in this answer, at the cost of a floating-point division at every iteration. The first difference is `9 * 0.1f`, which is slightly more wrong than `9 / 10.0f`. ideone.com does not have extended precision for `long double`, apparently, but running this program on a platform that does would show that: http://ideone.com/XDRzrO . When I run it, I get 0xe.68887cccc8aeeedp-7 for the sum of errors with multiplication and 0xc.599996665a0cccdp-7 for division.

Comment: @PascalCuoq the distribution of errors is why I left my answer there, but you are right, I didn't even think about the performance impact of the FP division - which is not something to look over in large iterations... I would always try to use powers of two approach in such situations - considering negative powers too, as with them, bitwise shift operators can be used for division and multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

> binary floating-point number cannot represent exactly 1

[Proof that it can can be found here](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049046048).

> Most accurate representation = 1.0E0

There could be problems with

1. fractional numbers that would have infinite fractional digits in radix of 2
2. numbers that are too small to exactly represent without losing precision
3. numbers that are too large to represent without losing precision.

But **`1.0`** is none of them!

**However** ***`0.1`*** is a problem case, violating point number 1, look at [this](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=048046049):

> Most accurate representation = 1.00000001490116119384765625E-1

So if you add up 0.1 ten times, you will get `1.00000001490116119384765625E-0` which is greater than `1.0`.

(examples are in IEEE754 single precision 32 bit floating point numbers)

### Possible solution:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i <= 10; i++) {
    t=i/10.0;
    curves_error error = curves_bezier(points, point, t);
    if (error != curves_no_error) {
        printf("Error with t = %f.\n", t);
    }
    else {
        printf("t = %f is ok.\n", t);
    }
}
```

This way, the error of the binary format does not get summed up!

(**Note:** I used extra curly braces for the `if` and `else` statements. Do that, you'll thank yourself one day.)

Answer (score 2):

When comparing floating point numbers you should check if they are close enough not exactly equal, for the reasons mentioned in other answers, something like:

```
#define EPSILON 0.000001f
#define FEQUAL(a,b) (fabs((a) - (b)) < EPSILON)
```

Comment: Ah right, it was *EPSILON* not *ELLIPSIS* :D Thanks for the example, could be usefule someday.