# what's is going wrong with this loop condition?

Tags: c

Look at the output of [this link](http://ideone.com/7oK3Xl)(scroll down to see the output) to find out what I'm trying to accomplish

The problem is with the `for` loop on line number 9-11

```
for(i=0; i<=0.9; i+=0.1){
  printf("%6.1f ",i);
}
```

I expected this to print values from 0.0 until 0.9 but it stops after printing 0.8, any idea why ??

Comment: Don't use floating points for iteration.

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of floating point representation.

Comment: because 0.8 + 0.1 is probably something more like 0.9000001. Floats can virtually NEVER exactly represent decimal numbers accurately.

Comment: Debug to see what `i` is in each step.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, Marc: I thought it was only javascript :(

Comment: Obligatory link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Unspecified: pretty much all the languages. some provide decimal numbers, but if you use floats... this is what happens :)

Comment: If you want to compare use double

Comment: @Unspecified: No, it's the nature of floating points, no matter what language.

Comment: has anybody actually read that obligatory doc? :) it's waaaaay to long, even for a pro programmer.

Comment: @MarcB Actually they can, up to: 2^24. Did you mean to say floats can't represent real numbers accuratelly.

Comment: [Link to YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0)

Comment: @MarcB Is it random ? I mean it doesn't happen with 15-17 line numbers

Comment: @valter: don't. that won't help.

Comment: @Unspecified: wouldn't say "random", since converting base10 -> base2 is a simple mathematical transform, but for all intents and purposes, you might as well TREAT it as random. floats shouldn't be used as loop iterators, unless you know how to handle issues like this exact one.

Comment: @self. The last 2 characters didn't copy. Link corrected.

Comment: @MarcB okay, going through the link & the video :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using float here is source of problem. Instead, do it with an int:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
   printf("%6.1f ", (float)(i / 10.0));
```

Output:

```
0.0    0.1    0.2    0.3    0.4    0.5    0.6    0.7    0.8    0.9    1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Ideally floating point should not be used for iteration, but if you want to know why change your code and see how.

```
for(float i=0; i<=0.9f; ){
    i+=0.1f;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Here is the result.

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.70000005
0.8000001
0.9000001
```

your 9th value exceeds 0.9.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't `0.9` in C also exceed 0.9 by the same amount?

Comment: Yes it does, here difference is, the increment is before printing the value.

Comment: Actually the key thing here is _accumulation_ of errors due to summing - see my answer for at test case

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is inexact in computing.  This is because of the way that a computer represents floating point values.  Here's an excerpt from an MSDN article on the subject:

> Every decimal integer can be exactly represented by a binary integer; however, this is not >true for fractional numbers. In fact, every number that is irrational in base 10 will also be >irrational in any system with a base smaller than 10.
>
> For binary, in particular, only fractional numbers that can be represented in the form p/q, >where q is an integer power of 2, can be expressed exactly, with a finite number of bits.
>
> Even common decimal fractions, such as decimal 0.0001, cannot be represented exactly in >binary. (0.0001 is a repeating binary fraction with a period of 104 bits!)

Link to the full article: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/42980

Answer (score 1):

Floating point number cannot precisely represent decimals, so rounding errors accumulate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float literal = 0.9;
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        sum += 0.1;

    cout << setprecision(10) << literal << ", " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.8999999762, 0.9000000954
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop is right, but the float comparison in loops is not safe.
The problem is that a [binary floating point number cannot exactly represent 0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512986/floating-point-number-imprecision-while-iterating)

This would work.

```
    for(i=0.0; i<=0.9001; i+=0.1){
           printf("%6.1f ",i);
```